.Net MAUI Hybrid - PDF preview in Windows and MAC
I tried .NET MAUI hybrid app for file preview. In windows used base64 string but that method not worked in MAC
I need solution for how to file preview in .Net MAUI hybrid . documents are PDF, DOC/DOCX,XLXS,PPT.
Used VisualStudio 2022 and .NET 8

Macos has a Preview App which can view Image, PDF or other files on Mac. View PDFs and images in Preview on Mac
